# Web service implementation Java EE

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I have web service cloud system based on Java EE. I use jboss as application server, java version 1.7

My system is something like a bridge between client and merchant servers. Client sends data via soap protocol (amount USD, merchantID, paymenttype and so on.) and i make service implementation based on requested params and send back to client.

I have a question:

There are two ways to make core implementation,

1 is to run it in main thread, every web service runs in main thread
2 per service call should be in separate thread.

I don't want code examples or anything, just what is the correct way to determine my solution?

Comment: I would suggest you use something like Netty or Jetty to handle the web server side. Writing a multithreaded server is highly non-trivial and given that you are asking this question I would suggest that you do not attempt it. Look into, for example, Spring Boot or Spring Integration, for end to end solutions for what you want to do.

Comment: What's wrong with jBoss threadpool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jboss request processing thread pool to control it. There does not seem to be a reason to attempt custom thread pool. Its a a complete different discussion if you are thinking about asynchronous communication.

I got the below from another SO post which is helpful
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-performance/jboss-as-7-performance-tuning?start=3

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I designed my system as multiple threads managed by main thread. This solution is very helpful and easy to maintain.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @amdixon I think it looks like an answer. Not a very thorough one, but an answer anyway.